# Library errors with pmdarima and statsmodels

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I have a problem with some libraries for time series.
In particular first error rise when i import this library

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
```

As suggested in another post I use the command `!pip install pmdarima` to solve this problem. But then I have to restart the runtime otherwise I can't compile and I also have to re-use the command every time I open my colab/jupyter notebook.

So my ***first question*** is related to this issue. Is there any solution to avoid this process every time?

The ***second problem*** is connected to the first one, because I import other libraries that are:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import datetime as datetime
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from dateutil.parser import parse
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pmdarima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
```

According to the fact that I know how to solve the first problem, then I have several lines of code related to the time series prediction and when I have to use a function where I'm using the ARIMA model:

```
def Predict(train,test,Order1,Order2,Order3,parForecastLenght=31):
   
    # Build Model
    model = ARIMA(train.astype("float32"), order=(Order1, Order2, Order3))  
    fitted = model.fit(disp=-1)  

    # Forecast
    fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(parForecastLenght, alpha=0.05)  

    # Make as pandas series
    fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test.iloc[0:parForecastLenght].index)
    lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index=test.iloc[0:parForecastLenght].index)
    upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index=test.iloc[0:parForecastLenght].index)

    # Plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,5), dpi=100)
    plt.plot(train, label='training')
    plt.plot(test, label='actual')
    plt.plot(fc_series, label='forecast')
    plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, lower_series, upper_series, color='k', alpha=.15)
    plt.title('Forecast vs Actuals')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)
    plt.show()
    return fc_series
```

when I use try to execute this code:

```
model1 = Predict(train_Att_Assunzioni,test_Att_Assunzioni,0,0,0,30)
```

appears this kind of error:

```
NotImplementedError: 
statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have
been removed in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the .
between arima and model) and statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX.

statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA makes use of the statespace framework and
is both well tested and maintained. It also offers alternative specialized
parameter estimators.
```

So again I check posts on stackoverflow, I tried to implement the suggested operations, but nothing seems to work except for the substitution of the library from `from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA` to `from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA`
but then the first problem rise again.

N.B. I tried to install statsmodels, pmadarima, I tried to change my work enviroment from colab to jupyter lab, but nothing

Comment: You have the wrong `ARIMA` for the current statsmodels.  You need to use `from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I've tried also this solution, but the error doesn't change.
I've also tried to uninstall and re-install all, but nothing changed

Comment: In the traceback, what command is leading to the NotImplementedError?